# which of the following functions $f$ are ( sesquilinear) form on $\mathbb{C}^2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

This problem is taken from Hoffman-Kunze book page no : $3324$, section $9.2$

Which of the  following functions $f$, defined on the vector $ a= (x_1,x_2), b= (y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{C}^2 $   are  ( sesquilinear) forms on $\mathbb{C}^2$ ?

$1.$$ f(a,b) = 1$

$2.$ $f(a,b) = (x_1 - \bar y_1)^2 + x_2\bar y_2$

$3.$$f(a,b) = (x_1 + \bar y_1)^2 - (x_1 - \bar y_1)^2$

$4.$ $f(a,b) = x_1\bar y_2 - \bar x_2 y_1$

My attempt: For  a sesquilinear form,   we have   $f(ka_1 +b_1 , c_1) = k f(a_1,c_1) + f(b_1, c_1)$.

Now  comparing with  this,  I got $b_1= 0$, that is, for option $1$ $f(a_1+0,c_1)=f(a_1,c_1) + f(0,c_1)$ that is  $f(a,b) = f(a,b) + f(0,b)= 1$

Here I'm confused  how to check other option also.

Comment: What is the definition of "sesquilinear form" that you are using?

Comment: @TheoBendit i used from the books  Hoffman   it given on book

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option $1.$ is not true  because  $f(0,b) \neq 0$

option $2.$ is false  because $f((0,0),(1,0)) \neq 0$

option $3.$ is true $f(a,b) = 4x_1\bar y_1$

option $4.$ is false because  of $\bar x_2$ there , it is not linear on $a$